# Does the Material3 DatePicker component violate unidirectional data flow in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, architecture, android-jetpack-compose

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf-compose) for unidirectional data flow has the following description:

> Composables work based on state and events. For example, a TextField is only updated when its value parameter is updated and it exposes an onValueChange callback—an event that requests the value to be changed to a new one. Compose defines the State object as a value holder, and changes to the state value trigger a recomposition.
>
> The type of the TextField composable's value is String, so this can come from anywhere—from a hardcoded value, from a ViewModel, or passed in from the parent composable. You don't have to hold it in a State object, but you need to update the value when onValueChange is called.

If I needed a `TextField` as a child component, then I would do this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Search(text: String, setText: (String) -> Unit) {
  TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { setText(it) })
}
```

I think it's definitely in line with the principle of unidirectional data flow.

However, I think DatePicker violates the principle of unidirectional data flow.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SageDatePicker(datePickerState: DatePickerState){
  DatePicker(state = datePickerState)
}
```

Disclaimer I just started learning android jetpack compose, but I have some experience with React development, so here is my opinion:

`DatePicker` does not modify `value` by sending an event, but directly modifies `value`. This means that the value of the parent component is directly modified in the child component, which should violate the principle of unidirectional data flow.

But Material3 Component is officially developed by Google, something doesn't seem right.

I can understand that the actual development does not necessarily need to follow the principle, but can you explain why there is such a situation that violates the principle of single data flow?